# How to read an RDD element (a list in dictionary format) and convert it to tuples readable by Pyspark API?

Tags: api, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I have an assignment question that I must use Pyspark RDD API to handle it.

I have a log file that contains:

```py
{"ID": "John", "Product": "955250", "Review": "I think its good enough, though it could be more END", "Rating": 3.0, "Date": "08 9, 1997"}','{"ID": "Smith", "Product": "B002KXA", "Review": "This is really hard to use and crappy implementation. That's what you get for using crap ingredients!! END", "Rating": 1.0, "Date": "08 10, 1997"}','{"ID": "Wayne", "Product": "630AA9", "Review": "...I go crazy over this movie!!... END", "Rating": 5.0, "Date": "06 21, 1997"}
```

When I do:

```py
product_review = sc.textFile("product_review.log")
product_review.collect()
```

I can see the output as:*

```py
['{"ID": "John", "Product": "955250", "Review": "I think its good enough, though it could be more END", "Rating": 3.0, "Date": "08 9, 1997"}','{"ID": "Smith", "Product": "B002KXA", "Review": "This is really hard to use and crappy implementation. That's what you get for using crap ingredients!! END", "Rating": 1.0, "Date": "08 10, 1997"}','{"ID": "Wayne", "Product": "630AA9", "Review": "...I go crazy over this movie!!... END", "Rating": 5.0, "Date": "06 21, 1997"}']
```

But when I try to do groupByKeys, the RDD element is not a dictionary.

How do I code and parse each rows so that Pyspark can read the list into rows of keys and values so that I can do transformation like distinct to count the number of unique IDs?

I hope the output can be transformed into something Pyspark RDD groupByKeys or ReduceByKeys can be used...
E.g.?

```py
[[("ID", "John"),("Product", "955250"), ("Review", "I think its good enough, though it could be more END"), ("Rating", 3.0), ("Date", "08 9, 1997")], [("ID", "Smith"), ("Product", "B002KXA"), ("Review", "This is really hard to use and crappy implementation. That's what you get for using crap ingredients!! END"), ("Rating", 1.0), ("Date", "08 10, 1997")], [("ID", "Wayne"), ("Product", "630AA9"), ("Review", "...I go crazy over this movie!!... END"), ("Rating", 5.0), ("Date", "06 21, 1997")]]
```

Appreciate for any advice how to go forward!

Comment: Hi! Please can you format the code/json in your Question? This will make it much easier for Users to read through your Question and hopefully find a solution for you.

Comment: ok sure! thank you!